# HTML/CSS/JS - How to change and image and text on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I get an image and the text under the image to swap when I click on a different image in the gallery?

I would like to have 4 thumbnail images that swap to an enlarged image when clicked, and  each displays a different description for each image under the enlarged one. I have managed to get the images to swap but I don't know where to start with the text part.

I would also like to have titles/links next to each image that can be clicked to change both the image and text underneath the image.

Code is below and in this JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/hzjk077t/

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title> Locations </title> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script src="image_swap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="branding">
        <img src="Images/logo.png">
    </div><!-- end of "logo" -->
    <div id="tagline">
    <p> Welcome to yourday.com - We hope you enjoy your visit! </p>

    </div><!-- end of "tagline" -->
</div><!-- end of "header" -->

<div id="bodycontent2">

    <div id="Thumbnails">
        <p>Below, we have a selection of vintage locations across Ireland and some information regarding each. 
        </br>Please take note of the location of your preference, and <a href="mailto:bookings@yourday.com">contact us</a>&nbspto to set up an appointment.
        <p>Select an image to enlarge it</p>
        <ul class="Thumbnails">
            <li><a href="slideshow/img1.jpg" title="location1"><img src="thumbnails/location1.jpg" alt="location1" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="slideshow/img2.jpg" title="location2"><img src="thumbnails/location2.jpg" alt="location2" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="slideshow/img3.jpg" title="location3"><img src="thumbnails/location3.jpg" alt="location3" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="slideshow/img4.jpg" title="location4"><img src="thumbnails/location4.jpg" alt="location4" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--end of thumbnail div -->

    <div id="main-image">
        <img src="slideshow/img1.jpg" alt="Enlarged Image" id="the_image" />
    </div><!--end of main image div-->
</div><!--end of body content" -->


<div id="navigation">
<ul class="topnav" id="TopNav">
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="locations.html">Locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="booking.html">Booking</a></li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>

    </li>
</ul>
</div> <!--end of "navigation" -->

<div id="footer">
  <p>Created by: Calvin Leong</p>
  <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:calvin.leong@CLDesign.com">calvin.leong@CLDesign.com</a></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
        font-family: Verdana, Helvetic, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: #C8A2C8;
        line-height: 125%

}

/*Map - where we are*/
h1{
    position:absolute;
    top: 450px;
}

#map{
    position:absolute;
    top:500px;
}
h2{
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: italic;

}

#navigation a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.highlight {
    color: #339999;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
    font-style:italic:
}

#navigation {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 150px;
    width: 100%
}

 #bodycontent {
     position: absolute;
     top: 620px;
     width: 100%
 }

 #tagline {
     position: absolute;
     top: 200px;
 }

 #bodycontent2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    width: 100%
}

/* Navigation bar */
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFB6C1;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #D3D3D3;}

/*Keeps footer at the bottom, no matter what size window*/
html{
    position:relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-width: 0 0 100% 0;
    border-color: gray;
}

/*Gallery settings*/
.galleryphoto {
    font-size: 65%;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 430px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid navy;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#main-image {
        margin: 0.2em 0 0 22em;
        }

#thumbnails p {
        font-size: 80%;
        }

#thumbnails ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        }

#thumbnails li {
        display: block;
        padding: 5% 0 0 0;
        }

#thumbnails {
        width: 16em;
        border-right: maroon;
        border-width: 0 3px 0 3px;
        border-style: dotted solid double;
        padding: 0 1.5%;
        float: left;
        height: 31.5em;
        }

#thumbnails a img {
        border-style: none;
        border-width: 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        }
```

**JS**

```
function swap_image() {
    var my_image = this.href;
    var the_image = document.getElementById("the_image");
    the_image.src = my_image;
    return false;
    }

function attach_handlers() {
    var div = document.getElementById("Thumbnails");
    var links = div.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (var i=0; i < links.length; ++i)
        links[i].onclick = swap_image;
    }

window.onload = attach_handlers;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved easily with jQuery.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blakecodes/vjksfvot/1/)

```js
// When you click the image
$('#image1').on('click', function () {
    // Select a div matching the CSS selector '#image1text'
    // Then set the HTML to 'image text here'
    $('#image1text').html('image text here');
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<img id="image1" src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg">
<div id="image1text"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. So for the 4 images,  I can just change the "image1text" to image 2 etc etc and it'll change to image 2 and image 2 text? Also, is it possible to have the previous text disappear and be replaced by the new text when a different image is selected?

Comment: Yes it is. If you wanted to do that, just do: $("#imagetext1").html(' '). That replaces the current text with nothing. If this is correct please mark it as the correct answer for future viewers.

Comment: Thank you. I've just tried to do it there, but it's not displaying the image text under the enlarged image. It is only displaying it under each thumbnail image. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/0fk2sn28/)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use overlays instead of links that go directly to the image.

```js
function popup(imageURL)
{
  document.getElementById("image").src = imageURL;
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = "Image is " + imageURL + ". You may put any HTML here as you like.";
}
```

```html
<p>Here are some image thumbnails...</p>
<div style="display: table-row;">
  <div style="display: table-cell;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x250?text=LOL" onclick="popup('http://placehold.it/200x250?text=LOL+Enlarged');">
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x250?text=A" onclick="popup('http://placehold.it/200x250?text=A+Enlarged');">
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x250?text=LOLOL" onclick="popup('http://placehold.it/200x250?text=LOLOL+Enlarged');">
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x250" onclick="popup('http://placehold.it/200x250');">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="overlay" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: calc(100% - 40px); height: calc(100% - 40px); opacity: 0.8; background-color: black; display: none; text-align: center; padding: 20px;">
  <img id="image">
  <br><br>
  <label id="caption" style="color: white;"></label>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

PS: If I'm not answering the question, please tell me...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, forgive my poor English.

If I understand you correctly, you want to change the img to be the one that you
had clicked.

Your "href" in your  link is used incorrently.

if you want to get these images title to print to the image,you can create a attribute in the images or your link,like 'data-location'.

link's href attribute is usually used to link to the website(href="https://www.google.com") or to this page's floor which you want to(href="#floor1").

Here's my demo.

https://jsbin.com/xolisefofi/edit?html,js,output
I hope it helps you.